# Grouping maps/structs by key, and summing the associated values for an array

Tags: arrays, go, maps, aggregate

I have an array of structs that i've built by getting a word frequency count for a list of sentences. The output from this is the most popular words **per sentence**. I need it across all sentences

Here are the structs:

```
type WordCountStruct struct {
    word string
    freq int
}

type WordCountStructArray []WordCountStruct
```

This is a sample of the WordCountStructArray:

```
[{the 8} {and 8} {to 7} {and 6} {and 6}]
```

So what this is is an ordered list, for each sentence, of the most common words. **I need to group by the key, and sum the values**

In the case of the 5 sample set above, this would result in:

```
[{the 8} {to 7} {and 20}]
```

I can convert the struct to a []map[string]interface{} if this is easier?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is something like this what your looking for?

```
package main

import "fmt"

type WordCountStruct struct {
    word string
    freq int
}

type WordCountStructArray []WordCountStruct

func main() {
    wCounts := WordCountStructArray{
        WordCountStruct{"the", 8},
        WordCountStruct{"and", 8},
        WordCountStruct{"to", 7},
        WordCountStruct{"and", 6},
        WordCountStruct{"and", 6},
    }

    fmt.Println(wCounts)

    freq := make(map[string]int)
    for _, wCount := range wCounts {
        freq[wCount.word] += wCount.freq
    }

    fmt.Println(freq)
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/oCqfoCy_W2g

Comment: Thanks a lot Kent, that was a nice and easy solution. In my final result I then converted back to the struct, so that I can sort the values and get a top n list. Thanks again